# Control size of text-only buttons in QToolBar

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, toolbar

I'm using PySide. I have a QMainWindow with a vertical QToolBar `myToolBar`. I use `myToolBar.toolButtonStyle = Qt.ToolButtonTextOnly` to make the toolbar's buttons contain only text, no icons. I add QActions to the QToolBar, and buttons are automatically created. I'd like to make the buttons taller, but since I'm not using any QToolButton objects, I don't know how. QAction has a setFont() method, so I can make the font larger, but what I want is some padding inside the button. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#qtoolbutton-widget

Something like the following should do it:

```
myToolBar.setStyleSheet("QToolButton{padding: 20px;}");
```

Basically that says, set the style for any widgets underneath this object of the type `QToolButton`, to have the QStyle set for padding on all four sides set to 20px.

If you only wanted to set the padding on the top and right sides, it would look like this:

```
padding: 20px 0px 4px 0px;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp